# How to set up an anonymous blog?

Tags: web-application, anonymity

I intend to create a completely anonymous blog. My threat is not the government but, the hackers who might disagree with the content of my blogs. I also want to eventually be able to monetize this blog. Can anyone please tell me the best way to go about doing this? If this is impossible please tell me how to be as safe as possible while still being able to monetize it?

Comment: How are you defining 'anonymous'? I'm very confused about what exactly you want to do here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9504/how-can-i-keep-my-identity-anonymous-as-a-website-owner-administrator?rq=1 ?

Comment: By "anonymous" I don't want anyone to figure out my identity through the blog.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to perform the above task. Many third-party software and applications are available allowing you to be anonymous.
Some important points include:

- Making sure your IP address is hidden or spoofed.
- Utilities like traceroute are not able to route your PC or device.
- The email address you are using is not trackable back to you.
- Cover your tracks.
- TOR is a nice solution.
- Using Cryptocurrency, like Bit-coins, in case you want to monetize your blog.

These are two links that will help you set up anonymous blogs:
1. [Link One](http://www.wefightcensorship.org/article/how-blog-anonymouslyhtml.html)
2. [Link Two](http://www.ethanzuckerman.com/blog/2006/10/01/anonymous-blogging-with-wordpress-and-tor/)

Answer (score -2):

Purchase a VPS and domain name using Bitcoin and using a pseudonym, and then connect to the VPS only though Tor. Then, make sure the blog doesn't contain personally identifiable information, such as your social media profiles, etc. Use common sense.